# Django appends to host instead of website name

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to use the `@user_passes_test(function, login_url)` decorator on a production server, but it seems `login_url` is not getting appended as `host/mysitename/login_url` but only as `host/login_url`. Everything works correctly from a local machine, though. The problem only appears when I'm trying to run it on the server. I have already set `LOGIN_URL` in the `settings.py`file, but the problem is that I need to send the user to a different login page, since they need to be authenticated via LDAP.

Changing `login_url` to `/mysitename/login_url` works, but isn't there a better, more elegant solution to this?

Comment: relative urls are always relative to the host, how is django supposed to know it should add `mysitename`? Also how does it work on your dev machine, that's not clear. There's no such thing as a website name to prefix all urls.

Comment: In any case, the `login_url` is the url to redirect to, Django doesn't append it to the host, it just sends it back as relative path in the HTTP 302 redirect `location`. So there's no appending of host taking place, your browser is instructed to redirect to the relative location "login_url". Just make sure "login_url" is correct (by appending the websitename yourself, which is what you're already doing).